# Can kafka server be installed with dotNet

Tags: apache-kafka

Can kafka server be installed with dotnet?

I'm finding it goes with JVM. Without JVM can it work in dotnet tech stack?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Server requires the JVM, yes. It cannot run without the JVM.

Kafka Clients support multiple languages, including  .NET

Comment: Thanks Robin Moffatt
Is this primarily due to Zookeeper dependancy?

Comment: No, it's due to the fact it's written in Java :) I get the impression you have a concern beyond just the runtime. After all, regardless of the JVM, you can still use it with .NET clients, since the API itself is not tied to the JVM. If this is the case and there is a more nuanced element to your question, please edit your question to expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `microsoft kafka client` is not actively developed/supported. Instead the author recommends to use `rdkafka-dotnet` It has better documentation and is easy to use

https://github.com/Microsoft/CSharpClient-for-Kafka

https://github.com/ah-/rdkafka-dotnet

But confluent has a great .net kafka library. It's easy to implement consumer groups and highly configurable.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Confluent.Kafka/

Comment: Question asked about server, not clients